# Change WKWebView default context menu language

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that loads an URL which asks the user to upload an image by either taking a photo at that very moment or searching their photo library. The menu that appears is shown in English while my app & phone are in Spanish. Is there a way to change this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this item in info.plist file will solve this:

- keyname : Localized resources can be mixed (CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations)
- type : Boolean
- value : YES (1)